# node-webkit disable scrolling

Tags: google-chrome, node-webkit

does anybody now how to disable scrolling on node-webkit? I'm trying to use the zoom function from d3 and sometimes it zooms, sometimes it scrolls the page. I don't need the page to be able to scroll, so is there a way to disable it overall?

Thank you